Recursive C Macros
Question
Suppose I want to define a certain number of unique variables like so:
int toto0 = 0;
int toto1 = 0;
int toto2 = 0;

How can this be achieved with a single macro to which you pass a number, say like:
#define TOTO(n) // Magic

Investigations
I have looked into several SO answers, and one seemed particularly interesting for the topic: here
It basically describes an implementation of a mapping macro, and for my application I can achieve the desired result like so:
#define VAR(x) uint32_t toto##x = 0;
// Call to MAP
MAP(VAR,0,1,2)
// or using __COUNTER__
MAP(VAR,__COUNTER__,__COUNTER__,__COUNTER__)

However, it is not exactly the TOTO(n) concise macro, and would require me writing out all the parameters! Maybe again using a similar technique to the linked SO answer there is a way to expand __COUNTER__ n times and plug it into the function?

Standard C preprocessing features are for minor substitutions. Usually, you should avoid using it for anything requiring manipulations of source code by various calculations or sequencing or other complications. In situations where you need source code to be prepared according to an algorithm, you can write a program in any programming language to generate the desired source code, and then you can include that source code in your program with #include, along with suitable documentation for what is being done and why.

You can make such a macro for a defined maximum of n, but you will have to spell out each variant explicitly, at least partially, anyway within the macro implementation, simply because the preprocessor won't do any calculations with n for you and won't generate the 0..n sequence.

Frame challenge: why do you want multiple separate variables with the same type and related names? The more natural alternative would be to use an array.

The variables are just an example I actually need to accomplish something more complex that uses this pattern. As for the spelling out method, I am avare of It, but do want to avoid it

So short answer - you can't. There is no way the preprocessor would generate the numbers between 0 and n  if it is only given n

The site of the "99 bottles of beer" is not working for me at the moment. I'm pretty sure they have a C preprocessor version (probably not recursive though) :-) See http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/

Recursion requires conditional logic, so you can stop when you reach the base case. C macros can't evaluate conditions.

@pmg https://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-c-c++-preprocessor-115.html

It #includes the header file recursively, rather than calling the macro recursively. This allows you to put #include inside #ifdef.

Maybe it's just because the example is simple, but seeing variable names like that always raises the question "are you sure you don't just want an array?"

How about just using an array?

No sane programmer would ever want many variables named like that. Back to the drawing board.

Indeed, this is an XY question. You shouldn't want to have variables like that in the first place. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with these variables?

As previously said the variables are just an example! The actual problem is more complex and would hide the purpose of the question!


How can this be achieved with a single macro to which you pass a number, say like:


#define TOTO(n) // Magic


It cannot be achieved by and with a single macro.
Macro expansion is explicitly non-recursive  (C23 6.10.5.5/2).  You can produce limited-depth recursion-like effects via a suitable stack of multiple macros, but that gets ugly and hard to maintain very quickly.  For even moderately complex code generation you would probably be best off writing a separate code generator.


Write yourself a small C program to generate .h file with enough macros for your needs

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    if (argc != 2) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <number_of_variables>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (n <= 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please provide a positive integer for the number of variables.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("#ifndef DECL_VAR_H\n");    
    printf("#define DECL_VAR_H\n\n\n");    

    printf("#define DECL_VAR(name, index) int name##index = 0;\n\n");
    printf("#define CREATE_VARS(name, n) CREATE_VARS_##n(name)\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        if (i == 0) {
            printf("#define CREATE_VARS_0(name)\n");
        } 
        else 
        {
            printf("#define CREATE_VARS_%d(name) CREATE_VARS_%d(name) DECL_VAR(name, %d)\n", i, i - 1, i - 1);
        }
    }
    printf("\n#endif //DECL_VAR_H\n");    

    return 0;
}

https://godbolt.org/z/3ss917fhs

Generate the file (for 30 for example)

#ifndef DECL_VAR_H
#define DECL_VAR_H


#define DECL_VAR(name, index) int name##index = 0;

#define CREATE_VARS(name, n) CREATE_VARS_##n(name)

#define CREATE_VARS_0(name)
#define CREATE_VARS_1(name) CREATE_VARS_0(name) DECL_VAR(name, 0)
#define CREATE_VARS_2(name) CREATE_VARS_1(name) DECL_VAR(name, 1)
#define CREATE_VARS_3(name) CREATE_VARS_2(name) DECL_VAR(name, 2)
#define CREATE_VARS_4(name) CREATE_VARS_3(name) DECL_VAR(name, 3)
#define CREATE_VARS_5(name) CREATE_VARS_4(name) DECL_VAR(name, 4)
#define CREATE_VARS_6(name) CREATE_VARS_5(name) DECL_VAR(name, 5)
#define CREATE_VARS_7(name) CREATE_VARS_6(name) DECL_VAR(name, 6)
#define CREATE_VARS_8(name) CREATE_VARS_7(name) DECL_VAR(name, 7)
#define CREATE_VARS_9(name) CREATE_VARS_8(name) DECL_VAR(name, 8)
#define CREATE_VARS_10(name) CREATE_VARS_9(name) DECL_VAR(name, 9)
#define CREATE_VARS_11(name) CREATE_VARS_10(name) DECL_VAR(name, 10)
#define CREATE_VARS_12(name) CREATE_VARS_11(name) DECL_VAR(name, 11)
#define CREATE_VARS_13(name) CREATE_VARS_12(name) DECL_VAR(name, 12)
#define CREATE_VARS_14(name) CREATE_VARS_13(name) DECL_VAR(name, 13)
#define CREATE_VARS_15(name) CREATE_VARS_14(name) DECL_VAR(name, 14)
#define CREATE_VARS_16(name) CREATE_VARS_15(name) DECL_VAR(name, 15)
#define CREATE_VARS_17(name) CREATE_VARS_16(name) DECL_VAR(name, 16)
#define CREATE_VARS_18(name) CREATE_VARS_17(name) DECL_VAR(name, 17)
#define CREATE_VARS_19(name) CREATE_VARS_18(name) DECL_VAR(name, 18)
#define CREATE_VARS_20(name) CREATE_VARS_19(name) DECL_VAR(name, 19)
#define CREATE_VARS_21(name) CREATE_VARS_20(name) DECL_VAR(name, 20)
#define CREATE_VARS_22(name) CREATE_VARS_21(name) DECL_VAR(name, 21)
#define CREATE_VARS_23(name) CREATE_VARS_22(name) DECL_VAR(name, 22)
#define CREATE_VARS_24(name) CREATE_VARS_23(name) DECL_VAR(name, 23)
#define CREATE_VARS_25(name) CREATE_VARS_24(name) DECL_VAR(name, 24)
#define CREATE_VARS_26(name) CREATE_VARS_25(name) DECL_VAR(name, 25)
#define CREATE_VARS_27(name) CREATE_VARS_26(name) DECL_VAR(name, 26)
#define CREATE_VARS_28(name) CREATE_VARS_27(name) DECL_VAR(name, 27)
#define CREATE_VARS_29(name) CREATE_VARS_28(name) DECL_VAR(name, 28)
#define CREATE_VARS_30(name) CREATE_VARS_29(name) DECL_VAR(name, 29)

#endif //DECL_VAR_H


Include into your source file and enjoy by using CREATE_VARS(namem num); where num has to be constant expression

Example: CREATE_VARS(toto, 15);

You can also define macro TOTO

#define TOTO(n) CREATE_VARS(toto, n)


A C program for code generation? It's a bit masochistic :D I'd go with Python or other scripting.

@EugeneSh. I did not want to introduce new languages to the answer :)

@EugeneSh. he can also generate once a giant file with bit n and include it in his code. I do not think that anyone will have more than 1M similar variables :D

@EugeneSh. Masochistic !? And then you say Python ! It doesn't get much more masochistic than that.

@0___________ I think it would hit some compiler environmental limit when creating 1M similar variables anyway :-)

@IanAbbott Give it try ;-)

1+1 is a "constant expression" but no good here. You mean a decimal integer literal (or 0).

Using Boost.Preprocessor, you could write
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repeat.hpp>

#define DEFINE_INT_VAR(z, i, name) int BOOST_PP_CAT(name, i) = 0;
#define TOTO(n) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n, DEFINE_INT_VAR, toto)

TOTO(3)

Despite the *.hpp names, Boost.Preprocessor is entirely compatible with C.
BOOST_PP_REPEAT has a few implementations depending on the compiler, but all involve defining a lot of macros SOMETHING_0, SOMETHING_1, SOMETHING_2, etc., and then expanding BOOST_PP_CAT(SOMETHING_, n).

@0___________ Well it would work if it godbolt installed Boost.Preprocessor…

"Here's another site:" ??

Checked the source - it is exactly what my answer. I think it limited to BOOST_PP_LIMIT_REPEAT which is as I see typically set to 256

@0___________ Yes, 256, 512, or 1024.

Oops. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e134e090a945503f
